# How to implement multiple selection in f.select?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui

Previously I have created multiple selection in f.select, using

```
<%= f.select(:TYPE, Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, 
                                       { :prompt => "Please select"}, 
                                       { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
```

and it works fine.

Now categories have its own children and child need to be selected for given category. I tried my best to implement but unable to get success.

```
@category = Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
@subcategory = Category.first.subcategories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
```

I need 3 block, first for category second for subcategory and last for selected subcategory.

I will be thankful if anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The select tag in form look like:

```
<%= select_tag "categories", options_for_select(@allcategories, @allcategories.first) %>

<div id="multiselect-subcat">
  <%= render :partial => 'subcategories'  %>
</div>
```

Add a partial _subcategories.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @story, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>

<%= f.select(:category_ids, @subcategories.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] },
                               {:include_hidden => false},
                               {:class => 'multi-select', :multiple => true}) %>

<% end %>
```

Add a route to fetch subcategories

```
get 'fetch_subcategories'


 def fetch_subcategories
    @story = Story.new
    @subcategories = Category.where(parent_id: params[:category_id])
    render :partial => "subcategories", :locals => { :subcategories => @subcategories }
  end
```

To handle change event of category i.e when category is changed populate the subcategories

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#story_category_ids').multiSelect();
        });


        jQuery(function($) {
          $("#categories").change(function() {
            var category = $('select#categories :selected').val();

            if(category == "") category="0";

            jQuery.get('/stories/fetch_subcategories?category_id=' + category, function(data){
              $("#multiselect-subcat").html(data);
              $('#story_category_ids').multiSelect();
            })
            return false;
          });
        })


    </script>
```